# Mount NVME drive of C5d instance in Amazon Sagemaker Studio

Tags: amazon-sagemaker

Is it possible to mount the NVME drive of an C5d instance in an Amazon Sagemaker Studio notebook? I can see the drive under 'lsblk' but am not allowed to format or mount it. The drive is also not visible in the '/dev' folder. I tried this with a regular C5d EC2 instance and there it works without any issue.

Edit: I tested it with Sagemaker Notebooks, not Studio, and it also works. It seems Studio doesn't have real access to the underlying infrastructure.

Kind regards